# Código 1215 em SQL "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

Ao criar esse código sempre vem o erro:

> 1215 "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Já tentei de tudo, conferi as restrições de chave estrangeira e nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
create table alunodisc ( 
    codigodisc int, 
    mataluno int , 
    constraint PK primary key(codigodisc,mataluno), 
    constraint codalundisc foreign key (codigodisc) references disciplinas(codisc), 
    constraint matalundisc foreign key (mataluno) references alunos(mataluno)
);
```

Comment: Qual o motor de banco de dados? SQL Server? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: Eu uso o MySql.

Comment: https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/176772-resolvido-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/

Comment: Coloque a estrutura da tabela `alunos` e `disciplinas`.

Comment: O erro está afirmando que não pode adicionar uma constraint Foreign Key, acredito que você esteja referenciando um nome da coluna errado.

1 - Observe como está escrito o nome da coluna de cada tabela.

2 - Certifique-se que colocou chave primarias nas colunas que você está referenciando.

3 - Verifique se os nomes das colunas estão iguais na referencia.

Enfim, tudo indica que seja erro de digitação, o ruim do mysql e de outros bancos que ele não consegue mostrar exatamente onde está o erro, você tem que verificar linha a linha e as vezes a pessoa se passa.

Answer (score -1):

Para encontrar o erro específico, execute isso:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

E olhe na parte de `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR`.

A coluna que será estrangeira e a chave que ela referencia devem ser iguais nos tipos. Por exemplo uma não pode ser `SMALLINT` e a a outra `INT`

Além disso, você deve executar a consulta definir foreign_key_checks = 0 antes de executar o DDL para que você possa criar as tabelas em uma ordem arbitrária (Criando filhas antes de pais), caso não faça isso você deve criar as tabelas pais primeiro, depois as que usam como chave algum atributo da pai.

Answer (score -1):

Apontando coisas que chamam a atenção no seu código:

1. A referência estrangeira na FK `codalundisc` pode ser um erro de digitação:
   `codisc` ou `codigodisc`?
2. Os campos estrangeiros devem ser PK de suas respectivas tabelas, bem como do mesmo tipo de dados em ambas as tabelas (`int`, no presente caso).
3. As tabelas referenciadas (estrangeiras) devem ser criadas antes das
   FKs que as referenciam.

Considerando que não há *typo* como sugerido no item 1, verifique as PKs e a ordem da criação das tabelas. O código abaixo funciona ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a09d89)):

```
create table disciplinas (codisc int primary key);
create table alunos(mataluno int primary key);

create table alunodisc ( 
    codigodisc int, 
    mataluno int , 
    constraint PK primary key(codigodisc,mataluno), 
    constraint codalundisc foreign key (codigodisc) references disciplinas(codisc), 
    constraint matalundisc foreign key (mataluno) references alunos(mataluno)
);
```

Comment: Apenas uma observação: o MySQL não exige que o campo referenciado na chave estrangeira seja PK, apenas que o campo seja indexado. Note que o MySQL nem exige que seja declarado como UNIQUE e NOT NULL, como exigem outros SGBD.